# Is it possible to use DevForce with new .NET5, NET6?

Tags: wcf, devforce

As I know DevForce use WCF for the communications between client and server.
But in newer version of .NET (Core 3.1, .NET5, .NET6 etc) WCF services not supported.
Is it possible to configure DevForce to use endpoints based on GRPC\WebApi instead of WCF?

Comment: I've very interested in this as well.  My company is looking to move to .NET 5+ but DevForce is a major piece holding us back. I reached out to IdeaBlade a few years back via email asking this question.  It seems like their focus is elsewhere and things like Breeze are the future - so I wouldn't hold my breath on this one. At this point, one option that we are considering (which is probably crazy) is to try to make the necessary DevForce changes ourselves after buying a source code license.

Comment: I though there can be some workaround.. for example use interceptors on client and special handlers which will convert GRPC\WebApi to WCF request for the IdeaBlase on the service side. Buy source code.. not applicable for my case despite on the huge project. Thank you for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

As a trend for the future, you can try using gRPC, CoreWCF, and ASP.NET Core MVC instead of WCF. With the.NET upgrade, some technologies have been fully ported, but not WCF, and the replacement for WCF is the technology mentioned above.

[The following article](https://visualrecode.com/blog/wcf-alternatives-for-net5/) lists some of their characteristics for your reference, I hope it can help you.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My question about possible configuration of DevForce. It is a  library which allow to work with server-side EF model from .NET client. It based on WCF. But for now WCF is significant limitation to use DevForce with latest .NET.

Comment: Yes, WCF is not well adapted in the latest.NET, so there are gRPC, CoreWCF, etc to replace it.

Comment: Alternatives for WCF were mentioned in the question., but I am asking about DevForce configuration. Do you know how to use DevForce with GRPC or WebApi?

Comment: Is there any progress on this issue?

Comment: As you can see - still has no answer.

Comment: I wonder if [this article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-grpc-json-transcoding-for-dotnet/) will help you.

Comment: Thank you for the link to the interesting article, hovewer DevForce use WCF.. do you have any thoughts about workarounds to handle SOAP message with GRPC server endpoint?  For now it seems to there is no easy solution to configure DevForce to use different communication API (GRPC or REST).